# Variable is not getting exported

Tags: shell, unix

I am running the following simple code in a shell script , but it seems like it cant export the variable :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "
read aws_access_key
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$aws_access_key
```

After that I take the input from the user ,but  when I run echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID  I get a blank value .

Comment: If you echo from the parent shell (i.e. the one that ran `./your-script.sh`) that won't/can't work. You can export variable *up* the process tree. In that script it should work though.

Comment: There is only one shell I am running , and I am trying to echo right after running these three lines.

Comment: @IshuGupta, wrong: When you run your script (without using `source`, or its POSIX-compliant synonym `.`), that starts a second shell, which exits when the script does. Thus, when that script exits, its variables are no longer available.

Comment: `echo` **in** the script or **after** the script. That matters if you run the script as a script (`./your-script.sh`) as opposed to sourcing the script (`. you-script.sh`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run your script in the current shell by using:

```
source your-script # this runs your-script in the existing shell
```

...or, if using a POSIX shell...

```
. your-script      # likewise; that space is intentional!
```

not

```
./your-script     # this starts a new shell just for `your-script`; its variables
                  # are lost when it exits!
```

...if you want variables it sets to be available to the shell that calls it.

---

To be clear, `export` puts a variable in the current process's environment -- but environment variables are propagated down to child processes, not up to parent processes.

---

Now, if your goal is to define an interactive command that's easy to call, you might want to consider an entirely different approach altogether -- putting a function in your `.bashrc`:

```
awsSetup() {
  echo -n "Enter AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "
  read && [[ $REPLY ]] && export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$REPLY
}
```

...after which the user with this in their `.bashrc` can run `awsSetup`, which will run in the current shell.

Comment: @ammoQ, indeed. I prefer the bashism here, as too many people read `. foo` as a typo for `./foo`, but it's worth at least pointing out the POSIX form.

Comment: Is there a way I can do it in the current process?

Comment: @IshuGupta, that's why I point out the `source` form.

Comment: @IshuGupta, ...I've also added a demonstration of another approach -- defining a command via a shell function rather than an external script.